# Unable to connect to hbase using phoenix jdbc driver (Can't get the locations error)

Tags: hadoop, jdbc, hbase, apache-phoenix

I am working on hbase(1.2.6) with phoenix(4.10.0-Hbase-1.2).
I am getting this error :

> org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Can't get the locations error

Below is my code through which I am trying to connect to hbase using phoenix:

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost");
```

Below is my hdfs-site.xml file where I have made some changes:
[image]

What changes I need to do? Please suggest..

Comment: in your jdbc url perhaps add localhost:2181 or localhost:12181 to point to the zookeeper so it can find your HBase+Phoenix co-processors?

Comment: yes i tried like  Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost:12181");  and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

A combined answer with @vrb

The Zookeeper port is a non-standard port, and needs to be specified on the jdbc url used with the Connection/DriverManager

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:localhost:12181");
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the "conf/regionserver" file in hbase for hostnames and use the same hostname to connect to hbase.

```
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:phoenix:{hostname_in_regionserver_conf_file}:2181");
```

Also ensure that the "phoenix-X.X.X-HBase-X.X-client.jar" jar is in the classpath of you java file.